# Change "Expand" button text color while div is expanded using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a div which is hidden until the user clicks the "expand" causing the div to expand revealing the content. When the div is expanded the word "expand" changes to "contract" and contracts the div again on click.

I'd also like the color of the clickable text to change from black to red when the div is expanded but I don't know how to do this.

The code I've used is as follows

In the body:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"><span>Expand</span></div>
<div class="content">Here's the contents to be hidden under the expand button</div>
</div>
```

in the style sheet

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .header {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container .header-expanded {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container .content {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
```

and here's the Javascript

```
 $(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";


        });
    });
});
```

Could someone please show me how to make the "collapse" text appear in red when the div is expanded? Sorry if this is obvious I'm very new to this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.toggleClass(className, state)](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state)

> A boolean value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.

Declare a CSS class,

```
.redColor {color : red}
```

*Code*

```
$header.toggleClass('redColor', $content.is(":visible"))
```